# Excel form to save data in access db

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have the below code for an excel form to currently save data in another excel.the only issue is that this doesn't work properly if more than 1 person are trying to send the data. Is it possible to make the code in a way that it sends data to an access db? Here my code.

```
Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()
Dim historyWks As Worksheet
Dim inputWks As Worksheet
Dim historyWb As Workbook '<~ target workbook

Dim nextRow As Long
Dim oCol As Long

Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCopy As String
Dim myCell As Range

'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
myCopy = "D5,D7,D9,D11,D13"

Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
Set historyWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\reports\consolidated.xlsx") '<~ open target workbook and     assign sheet
Set historyWks = historyWb.Worksheets("PartsData")

With historyWks
nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With inputWks
Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
    Exit Sub
End If
End With

With historyWks
With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
    .Value = Now
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
End With
.Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
oCol = 3
For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
    historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
    oCol = oCol + 1
Next myCell
End With

historyWb.Save '<~ save and close the target workbook
historyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False

'clear input cells that contain constants
With inputWks
On Error Resume Next
 With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
      .ClearContents
      Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
 End With
On Error GoTo 0
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone? :) I hope it's not too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to put data from Excel to an AccessDB:

```
Option Explicit
Dim con, rst, t0, i, s, xx, n
Const adUseClient = 3
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const useTransaction = True

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=e:\0\a\db1.accdb;"
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM Table1", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
If useTransaction Then
    con.BeginTrans
End If
i = 1
For i = 1 To Range("Dati").Rows.Count
    rst.AddNew
    rst("FirstName").Value = Range("Dati").Cells(i, 1).Value
    rst("LastName").Value = Range("Dati").Cells(i, 2).Value
    rst("Birday").Value = Range("Dati").Cells(i, 3).Value
    rst.Update
Next
If useTransaction Then con.CommitTrans
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

And put all the data inside Table1. All the data are taken from a Range named Dati.
I you have formula and you want to save formula use:

```
Range("Dati").Cells(i, 1).Formula
```

With This code you put ONLY the data from an Excel Files into a AccessDB file without check double data ...

Comment: Sounds awesome, thank u very much. Will try as soon as im back home and let u know :)

Comment: One a second note, I am trying to send data from a form into the accedd db by pressing a button,  as described above in my code. Can this code be changed to suit the requirement?

Comment: If I have understood well: rst("Nome").Value = TextBox1.Text ... removing the cycle For...Next - moving the code inside the button event.